# Altium Designer "NotFited" in BOM with DNP

Tags: altium, bom, designer

I heve problem with Altium BOM document generation. I want have multi variants of one project with some DNP elements. It's no problem if I want remove elements from BOM, for this I can add variants with some elements selected as "Not Fitted" and they aren't added to output BOM. But i want have elements with DNP in BOM for protect myself against mistake when I forgot add element (or elements) which should be mounted. Additionaly when i send PCB to factory with assembly options it's naturally that they ask me whats with missed elements in BOM? When I will add (to BOM) elements with DNP descriptions i resolve this two problems. Do you have any ideas for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create an output job with an output of type BOM, in the configuration dialog you can select to "include not fitted Components" which will give you an additional column of type (Fitted). Then, you can group by this column and AD will display unfitted components with an amount of 0.

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it as answered.